# Latex template for American Mathematical Monthly

Tags: math-mode, journal-publishing

I want to submit an article to *American Mathematical Monthly* and I am following the
"Instructions for authors" . 
It says that i should download their template.And i did.
But when i click "Typeset" I always get many errors even if i change some things in the code.
What is going on?Am I supposed to fix the whole code?

Sorry for being such a noob.
Thank you very much in advance.
Here is the code and [here is the link](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly#Submission)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maa-monthly}

%% IF YOU HAVE FONTS INSTALLED
%\usepackage{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{mathtime}

\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample Article Title}
\markright{Abbreviated Article Title}
\author{Woodrow Wilson and Herbert Hoover}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
An abstract should not contain concrete mathematics, but rather should be discrete.  Be brief and avoid using mathematical notation except where absolutely necessary, since this brief synopsis will be used by search engines to identify your article!
\end{abstract}


\noindent
The \textit{American Mathematical Monthly} style incorporates the following \LaTeX\ packages.  These styles should \textit{not} be included in the document header.
\begin{itemize}
\item times
\item pifont
\item graphicx
\item color
\item AMS styles: amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb
\item url
\end{itemize}
Use of other \LaTeX\ packages should be minimized as much as possible. Math notation, like $c = \sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$, can be left in \TeX's default Computer Modern typefaces for manuscript preparation; or, if you have the appropriate fonts installed, the \texttt{mathtime} or \texttt{mtpro} packages may be used, which will better approximate the finished article.

Web links can be embedded using the \verb~\url{...}~ command, which will result in something like \url{http://www.maa.org}.  These links will be active and stylized in the online publication.

\section{First-level section heading.}

Section headings use an initial capital letter on the first word, with subsequent words lowercase.  In general, the style of the journal is to leave all section headings unnumbered.  Consult the journal editor if you wish to depart from this and other conventions.

\subsection{Second-level heading.}

The same goes for second-level headings.  It is not necessary to add font commands to make the math within heads bold and sans serif; this change will occur automatically when the production style is applied.

\section{Graphics.}

Figures for the \textsc{Monthly} can be submitted as either color or black \& white graphics.  Generally, color graphics will be used for the online publication, and converted to black \& white images for the print journal.  We recommend using whatever graphics program you are most comfortable with, so long as the submitted graphic is provided as a separate file using a standard file format.

For best results, please follow the following guidelines:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bitmapped file formats---preferably TIFF or JPEG, but not BMP---are appropriate for photographs, using a resolution of at least 300 dpi at the final scaled size of the image.
\item Line art will reproduce best if provided in vector form, preferably EPS.
\item Alternatively, both photographs and line art can be provided as PDF files.  Note that creating a PDF does not affect whether the graphic is a bitmap or vector; saving a scanned piece of line art as PDF does not convert it to scalable line art.
\item If you generating graphics using a \TeX\ package, please be sure to provide a PDF of the manuscript.  In the production process, \TeX-generated graphics will eventually be converted to more conventional graphics so the \textsc{Monthly} can be delivered in e-reader formats.
\item For photos of contributing authors, we prefer photos that are not cropped tight to the author's profile, so that production staff can crop the head shot to an equal height and width.  If possible, avoid photographs that have excess shadows or glare.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Theorems, definitions, proofs, and all that.}

Following the defaults of the \texttt{amsthm} package, styling is provided for \texttt{theorem}, \texttt{definition}, and \texttt{remark} styles, although the latter two use the same styling.

\begin{theorem}[Pythagorean Theorem]
Theorems, lemmas, axioms, and the like are stylized using italicized text. These environments can be numbered or unnumbered, at the author's discretion.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proofs set in roman (upright) text, and conclude with an ``end of proof'' (q.e.d.) symbol that is set automatically when you end the proof environment.  When the proof ends with an equation or other non-text element, you need to add \verb~\qedhere~ to the element to set the end of proof symbol; see the \texttt{amsthm} package documentation for more details.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}[Secant Line]
Definitions, remarks, and notation are stylized as roman text.  They are typically unnumbered, but there are no hard-and-fast rules about numbering.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
Remarks stylize the same as definitions.
\end{remark}


\begin{acknowledgment}{Acknowledgment.}
The authors wish to thank the Greek polymath Anonymous, whose prolific works are an endless source of inspiration.
\end{acknowledgment}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{parker13} Adam Parker, Who solved the Bernoulli equation and how did they do it? \textit{Coll. Math. J.} \textbf{44} (2013) 89--97.

\bibitem{hopkins} Brian Hopkins, ed., \textit{Resources for Teaching Discrete Mathematics}, Mathematical Association of America, Washington DC, 2009.
\end{thebibliography}

\begin{biog}
\item[Woodrow Wilson] (twwilson@princeton.edu) received his PhD in history and political science from Johns Hopkins University. He held visiting positions at Cornell and Wesleyan before joining the faculty at Princeton, where he was eventually appointed president of the university.  Among his proudest accomplishments was the abolition of eating clubs at Princeton on the grounds that they were elitist.
\begin{affil}
Office of the President, Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544\\
twoodwilson@princeton.edu
\end{affil}

\item[Herbert Hoover] (hchoover@stanford.edu) entered Stanford University in 1891, after failing all of the entrance exams except mathematics.  He received his BS degree in geology in 1895, spent time as a mining engineer, then was appointed by his co-author to the U.S. Food Administration and the Supreme Economic Council, where he orchestrated the greatest famine relief efforts of all time.
\begin{affil}
Hoover Institution, Stanford University, Stanford CA 94305\\
herbhoover@stanford.edu
\end{affil}
\end{biog}
\vfill\eject

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you get also the `maa-monthly.sty` file? We need more info to help you. What was the first error?

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for the responce.Yes i did get the file.What am i supposed to do now?

Comment: What did you do with the `.sty` file? Is it in the same directory as the template/document you're trying to typeset? And @Sigur's question: What was the first error?

Comment: Everything is fine here: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/monthly-template.tex and http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/maa-monthly.sty at the same folder and run `pdflatex` on the `tex` file.

Comment: @Sigur this is what i see after doing the above:LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `',
               but the package provides `maa-monthly'.


! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \usepackage{
                times}

Comment: Check the line `\usepackage{maa-monthly.sty}` on `tex` file. Check the package name.

Comment: @Sigur Yes i checked it.What now?should i rename something?

Comment: Even without changing anything you are getting errors? I guess that you are having encoding problems. What is your editor?

Comment: @Sigur Yes i am getting errors.My  editor is Texworks.

Comment: Can you compile other documents or is this the only one you've tried? If so, try `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello Earthlings\end{document}` and see if that works. If not, what errors do you get?

Comment: @cfr I have compiled other documents succesfully.i really do not understand what is going on

Comment: @Sigur after i tried some things says: LaTeX Error: File `maa-monthly.cls' not found.

Comment: Then you are not trying to compile the code you posted. `maa-monthly` is *not* a document class. It is a *style*. You need e.g. `\documentclass{article}` *first* and then `\usepackage{maa-monthly}` *as shown in the template you posted*.

Comment: @cfr But i really am trying to compile the above code.I copy-pasted again the above code and when i tried to compile it i got the message :    ! LaTeX Error: File `maa-monthly.sty' not found

Comment: FWIW, I have just downloaded the template .tex and the .sty, and (with no alterations) they compile without error (pdflatex, xelatex, *and* lualatex). Are you able to compile OK *before* putting your own content into the template? Answering this will help us see whether it's a problem with your content or with your \TeX installation.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough yes before doing anything.What i need to do?Just download the 2 files put them in the same template and compile.Right?

Comment: Yes, I just downloaded the two files into the same folder, then compiled them with no problems.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough so,what is wrong?should i order the 2 files in some certain way or leave specific spaces between them or anything similar?

Comment: No, just leave them as two separate files ion the same folder, then process the .tex file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13054/discussion-between-brent-longborough-and-tango)

Comment: **Don't combine the files.** Just put both files in the same *directory* and compile the template. [Note that I can't contribute to chat although I can read it.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the record, this is the result of a well-known user interface design failure in Windows.

The files had somehow been downloaded as `maa-monthly.sty.tex` and `monthly-template.tex.tex`, but the Windows default folder options setting, of course, hides the true extension.

Renaming the files with their correct extensions fixed the problem.

A direct result of ridiculous User Mollycoddling by Microsoft Trying To Be Apple.

Comment: @tango I appreciate your kindness in trying to upvote me all over the site, but that particular approach has been foreseen by the site designers, and your work has been undone. We're happy to help here, and all you really need to do, if you feel you've had useful help, is to upvote the answer and accept it by clicking on the tick.

Comment: Just for the record: MacOS X does *not* obsessively/compulsively add filename extensions (e.g., `.tex`) when files are downloaded. :-)

Comment: @Mico Actually, I don't *think* it was Windows that added the extensions (it never has for me); the problem is, it conceals them.

Comment: I have experienced instances when Windows unhelpfully added filename extensions on its own, without me be aware of this behavior. The fact that the filename extensions are concealed by default makes this behavior even more problematic. (Full disclosure: I stopped using Windows for my "production work" long ago.)